# How to use Flickr Authentication in Android?

Tags: android, flickr

I'm pretty new to Android and want to build an app which allow user to login to their Flickr Account and allow them to upload photos. I have seen many articles, saw FlickrjAndroid but unable to understand how to get started. I also read the Flickr Api Documentation. Please guide me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`flickrj-androi` is a very good choice but you have to refer to their [API documentation](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) to make things easier, also make sure to check `Photo Upload API` section http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html

Comment: I am unable to understand two things, 1st how user is logged in to their Flickr account and 2nd is Flickr Api a XML Web Service? and can I consume it as all other XML Web Services in Android

Answer (score 0):

This is probably one of the best [getting started tutorials](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/07/access-flickr-api-using-httpclient.html) on Flickr Api for Android. Have a look, it should be of help.

Comment: What if I want only my photostream images of flickr ?